# Sharing and locking a fixed number resources of between multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, blocking

I have a fixed number `n` of identical resources that need to be shared between `n` or more threads. Whenever a thread needs to use a resource, it can take any available one, for which it runs an indetermininate amount of time (i.e. usage times are not uniform) and then release it.

What is a good Java data structure to manage this scenario? I can only think of one way to do it, which is by using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and the `take` and `put` operations as locking and releasing a resource, respectively. I'd just like a suggestion from the concurrency experts:

For those who are curious: The resources that need to be shared are identical copies of a [non-reentrant FORTRAN library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14553996/586086) for computing multivariate normal CDFs and moments. Spectacular numerical library, but written in an age where thread-safe code wasn't something to be worried about. In this case we make `n` copies of the library, where `n = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` .

**EDIT**: I don't want to create the overhead of threads to execute this library. It is already being called from multiple threads; the calling threads should just be able to lock a resource and get on with it.

**UPDATE**: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039878/586086 for the motivation and the implementation.

Comment: You can just create N tasks to add to a fixed size thread pool.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In my case I want the tasks to run synchronously from the perspective of the threads starting them. What benefit would I get by passing the jobs to different threads?

Comment: By "synchronously" you mean one after another? In that case you only need one thread.  The benefit of using multiple threads is they might be performed concurrently and thus take less time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry, I mean that the thread should block until the result is computed. I don't see why there would be a need to instantiate more threads in a pool, because the calling thread actually enters the native library.

Comment: Threads are always busy until finished.  Once you have a pool of threads you wouldn't create more.  Can you clarify what your doubt is?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am trying to make a non-reentrant library reentrant by making copies of it and having the calling threads take a lock on a unique copy before executing native code. There is no need to start a threadpool for this. I'm asking for a recommendation on using stuff like `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `Semaphore`, etc

Comment: So you want a pool of library resources you can use single threaded.  You can use an ArrayDeque or a linkedBlockingQueue as you suggest. A simpler approach is to give each thread a thread local copy. This avoids the overhead of allocating and freeing

Comment: @PeterLawrey what am I allocating and freeing? Since I need to make actual physical copies of the file library beforehand, how do you suggest giving each thread a thread-local copy if I don't know how many threads are going to be calling the library? Using a constant equal to the number of CPUs seems to make more sense. Also `ArrayDeque` does not block, are you talking about `ArrayBlockingQueue`?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your limitations as no one would design a system to work this way. I wouldn't block but instead create a new one as required. If you have to preallocate you risk doing too many or too little. In this case you need a blocking queue as there is nothing else you can do if you dont have enough resources.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, you wait for a resource to free up...but why would it matter if you can get it earlier if all CPU cores are being used anyway?

Comment: You can have threads which are not running which have not freed a resource.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't understand what's so difficult to comprehend about this. The following link is basically what I need to do; do you have any suggestions? https://github.com/mizzao/libmao/blob/master/src/main/java/net/andrewmao/misc/LibraryReplicator.java

Comment: The part which is difficult to comprehend is what is stopping you from doing it already.  That is why I am trying to guess what is holding you back.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did it already; that is my repo. I'm asking you if you have any suggestions based on my implementation.

Comment: It appears you are limited entirely by the library you have to work around.  To improve it you need to fix the use of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're describing is a [**resource pool**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). A thread-safe queue is a reasonable way to handle the situation when the resources are fairly simple, though you might also consider a pool library such as [pool4j](http://code.google.com/p/pool4j/).

Comment: Any other suggestions than a thread-safe queue? Pointers to any Java concurrent classes in particular?

Comment: You already identified the `BlockingQueue` interface. Given that you have a fixed number of library instances that won't change over the lifetime of the program, `ArrayBlockingQueue` might be a bit better than `LinkedBlockingQueue`, but you've been on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class with a list of fixed resource, and associated flag to mark each resource as available or unavailable, and 2 synchronized methods, something like:

```
synchronized Resource getResource(){
   find an unavailable resource, mark it as unavailable and return it
}

synchronized int returnResource(Resource r){
   find the matching resource on list and mark it as available.
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a thread-safe queue for what you just suggested?