# Are there cases where copies of shared libraries will share memory?

Tags: java, gcc, shared-libraries, jna, gfortran

In dealing with an old (but complicated) numerical library that I'm treating as a black box, I found that the library was not re-entrant. Hence, to make it safe to call from multiple threads, I created multiple copies of the library which are managed by a thread-safe queue. See the following questions for details:

- [Call a non-reentrant native shared library from multiple Java threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14553996/586086)
- [Sharing and locking a fixed number resources of between multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19031673/586086)

Basically, I have a library `mvnpack.so` which I've copied `n` times, `n` usually being the number of processors on my machine, into `mvnpack.so.i` for `i` from `0` to `n-1`. Then, each of these are mapped into a JNA interface. The copies themselves are identical to the byte.

Although I thought this would improve the throughput of the library and allow it to be used in parallel, the library is still exhibiting symptoms of re-entrancy problems such as weird numerical results, randomly returned `NaN` values, etc. I've isolated the problem from all other issues and it seems answer may to be a question that I don't know enough about:

> **If I map multiple identical shared libraries with the same code, but with different filenames to the memory space of the same process, are there cases where they will still share memory?**

The answers I received to my previous questions would indicate that this will not happen, but it seems like it does. If this is the case, are there any compiler or linker options that I can use that will prevent these copies from sharing memory? I'm using `gfortran` (`gcc`) to compile a shared library that is being mapped into a Java process by JNA.

Comment: Does the mvnpack.so possibly link to another library, which is not reentrant? (Also assuming you're really using copies, not hard links).

Comment: I imagine the symbols in your shared libraries are the same and I believe they need to be globally unique.  I suspect you need a process each for complete independence.

Comment: @kiheru no, it is its own library, and does not link to anything.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, shouldn't the symbols for each library be loaded into different memory addresses by JNA? JNA calls the mapped libraries something like like `mvnpack.so.x@somehexaddress` which is different for each copy.

Comment: @AndrewMao The hex value is a hashCode, not an address. The shared library is loaded by the kernel ultimately not JNA. I am not sure the symbols in different libraries can are allow to be the same but are treated as unique. ie. I don't think they have their own name space.

Comment: JNA by default loads libraries with the flag `RTLD_GLOBAL` (at least on linux).  You can pass different options at library load.  You should be able to compare the function pointers for the same function accessed via different copies (`NativeLibrary.getFunction()`).  There's also the possibility of the library making use of non-reentrant library functions itself (e.g `strtok` from the C library, or something from your fortran runtime).