# Fortran90: SAVE atribute or store in module?

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90, subroutine

I'm writing a program which will call a subroutine several times. This subroutine loops over a sum of terms, each divided by a factorial of the number of term (much like a Taylor series). It is always the same number of terms, so the dividing factorial are always the same. In order no to calculate the factorial in every call, it would be preferable to just define a vector once and then just divide (actually, multiply; I would define the vector as `1/n!`) by the corresponding coordinate. For example:

```
S=(T0)+(T1/1)+(T2/2!)+(T3/3!)+...+(Tn/n!)
```

(this will be calculated several times, for different arrays `T1,...,Tn`)

Which would be the best practice: to define it as a variable with the save attribute or to put it inside a module and include it in the subroutine? Or is there an even better option? (and why?)

From this other question ([fortran SAVE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893097/fortran-save-statement)), I would expect that the best thing to do is to use SAVE inside the subroutine (since I probably won't be using this variable in any other subroutine, I would have to use SAVE anyways), but I would welcome some feedback on this.

EDIT: Sorry, new addition. Assuming that the best thing to do is use SAVE; is it OK to define it as an allocatable variable? I know that allocatable variable and regular ones draw from different sections of the memory; I have no idea how this could interact with the SAVE attribute...(I would be relying on the program deallocating the variable automatically when exiting).

Answer (score 2):

Both choices are almost the same. Difference can arise when you initialize or finalize the variable.

You can initialize or do other things with the value of a module variable from any code that uses the module. The local variable of a subroutine is really local to it.

I don't see any reason why one or the other would be generally preferred, it depends on the overall structure of the program. And what is the exact purpose and usage of the variable.

I would slightly prefer the module. For large allocatable arrays you can more easily free the memory when needed without calling the subroutine with a special argument. Also you will have simple code of the subroutine without checking whether it is a first call or not.

Allocatable variable can be `save` without any problem. But there is no reason why local `save` variable would be generally the best.