# how can i keep variables private in subroutines which are called in a parallel section of openmp?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, private

i am calling a nested for loop as follows:

```
do ir = 1,Nr
    do iom = iom1, iom2
       xyz(1) = xo(1) + xom(iom)*r
       xyz(2) = xo(2) + yom(iom)*r
       xyz(3) = xo(3) + zom(iom)*r
       call FUNSUB(xyz,Nprop,PropXYZ)
    enddo
enddo
```

where `FUNSUB` evaluates a property in the following manner:

```
id = 1
do l=0,lmax
    do m=-l,l
        id = id + 1
        Prop(id) = RHO * Ylm(l,m,xl(1),xl(2),xl(3))
    enddo
enddo
```

now i am trying to parallelize this with something of the form

```
!$OMP parallel do reduction(+:Prop) private(ir, l, m, j, iom, r, wrad, xyz, PropOm, PropOm1, PropXYZ)
```

where some of the other private variables seen here are left out of my example code for brevity. i am intentionally trying to make `l` and `m` private so that inside the `FUNSUB` loops, the properties are evaluated independently. i find, however, that they are shared between threads. i have put in some debugging options and found that `id` continually goes above the bounds of `Prop` and have found that `l` also goes about `lmax` as well as `m` being outside the bounds of `(-l,l)`.

my question is: how do i go about making sure that `l` and `m` are kept private and NOT shared from the main routine? it seems that the problem is that it is an entirely different subroutine which holds these values and that, somehow these private declarations of variables do not carry over

Comment: Please post a full code of the FUNSUB. Correct usage of an external function in OpenMP region should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that in Fortran, [local subroutine variables can be static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582409/are-local-variables-in-fortran-77-static-or-stack-dynamic) and that the `!$OMP` does not propagate to called functions.

Your code should work as expected if you copy-paste `FUNSUB` into the calling loops, i.e. if you manually inline it.

**Update**

After reading-up a bit on the looniness of how local variables may or may not be implemented by the compiler, I guess your best option is to declare `FUNSUB` as `RECURSIVE`. This forces all local variables onto the stack, meaning that each OpenMP thread which calls `FUNSUB` will have its own, private, set of local variables.

Comment: i knew it was because i was calling an external function, but i want to find a way around inlining it because FUNSUB is actually a function handle passed to the subroutine and may be a different subroutine on different calls.

Comment: @Laurbert515: If your function is a function handle, then you're kind of stuck as OpenMP statements don't propagate to subroutines. How should the compiler know about that when compiling your subroutine? The only way around this is to either declare the variables in `FUNSUB` with the *opposite* of `SAVE` attribute, although I don't even know if this exists, or to pass them on as parameters to that function, which will be massively inefficient. There may be a compiler option that does the former.

Comment: @Laurbert515: Scratch the previous comment, the `RECURSIVE` keyword should solve all your problems. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The full code of the FUNSUB would have to be investigated. Correct usage of an external function in an OpenMP region should not be a problem. There should be no reason and it is not possible to declare variables in scope of an external function as private.

Modern Fortran compilers will not create local variables of a function static, if you don't tell it to do so. This may be done using a compiler switch (big NO NO in a parallel code) or by declaring the variables as SAVE as has been save. Note that all initialized variables are SAVE implicitly. That means that:

```
   integer :: local = 0
```

is SAVE even without the SAVE keyword and will be shared among threads.

It is a good practice to have all functions called in parallel declared as `PURE`. I am even for having all non-recursive functions at least effectively `PURE`.

Comment: funsub is actually a function handle so any function could be passed in for it, thus it is not possible to post the code of funsub.

Comment: Since `FUNSUB` actually seems to alter some of its input arguments, the keyword `PURE` will not work (see fourth point [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Pure_Procedures)).

Comment: In that case I am strongly against conszructing such procedures as functions and I know I am not alone. A subroutine should be used. If possible, a pure one

Comment: (i.e. see my last sentence of the answer)