# How to execute a command on the first and only first time entering fortran subroutine?

Tags: fortran

I wrote a subroutine for a Fortran program and I want to execute a command (delete file in the program directory and open a new one) the first, and only first time, the subroutine is called.  I know that I can achieve this by creating some flag outside of the subroutine, in the main program, that I set to false at program startup and then set to true upon entering the subroutine.  Then I could use this flag in an if statement to figure if the commands I want to execute on the initial call should be executed or not.  But this requires me modifying the existing program and I didn't want to do that if I could avoid it.  Is there some other way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582409/are-local-variables-in-fortran-77-static-or-stack-dynamic) for the `save` attribute to make variables static.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the 'save' attribute, but I'm not sure how I would use it for this case.

Comment: Using a static variable keeps the modification local to your function. A first call can clear the flag and succeeding calls can honor it.

Comment: How would the subroutine know that it is a first call and to subsequently clear the flag?

Comment: Initially it has a default value for example 0. And after that you increment it in every call. Than you can check if it is different from 0.

Comment: So, I would need to set the flag as zero outside of the subroutine, when the program starts, for example.  I wanted to see if I could do this without any modification to the code except for the call to my new subroutine.

Comment: Maybe I could compile my subroutine with a flag to initialize all variables to zero, so the flag will be guaranteed zero during the first call, and then non-zero afterwards?  Is there such a flag for ifort?

Comment: @rks171 - No.   You have the variable declared as, for instance, `logical, save :: firstcall = .TRUE.` and then have the initialization code do `if (firstcall) then ...  stuff .. firstcall = .FALSE. ; endif`.   Note that there's real downsides (threadsafety, eg) to using static variables, and a nicer way to do it would just be to have the calling function pass a flag to the routine to modify its behaviour the first time.

Comment: See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893097/fortran-save-statement/2893604#2893604 .   Inside of the If statement do your actions that you only want to perform on the first call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example might be:

```
subroutine test(a)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(inout) :: a
  logical, save :: first_time=.true.

  if(first_time) then
     first_time=.false.
     a = a + 12345
  else
     a = a - 67890
  end if

end subroutine test
```

Comment: Local variables with initialisers are implicitly saved, thus the explicit `save` attribute is redundant.

Comment: But for safety and clarity, why not add it?

Comment: I understand now.  I didn't realize that the declaration of first_time as .true. is only honored the first time the subroutine is entered.  I thought that every time that 'test' was entered, it would just keep setting first_time equal to .true. again.  Now I can see that the saved value is honored upon re-entry into 'test'.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about using some characteristic of the output file to determine whether or not to delete it?  Time stamp, file lock, a particular file extension, etc.